# Ruby on Rails3: how do I include non-standard methods in the routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

My routes.rb:

```
resources :board
root :to => 'application#index'
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

in my BoardController I have a method called `take_turn`

but when I click on a link that points to board#take_turn, I get the error:

```
Unknown action

The action 'show' could not be found for BoardController
```

The link looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/board/take_turn?x=0&y=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resources :boards do
  match 'take_turn', :on => :collection
end
```

Path by default: take_turn_boards_path

Answer (score 0):

```
match 'board/take_turn/:x/:y' => "board#take_turn", :as => 'take_turn'
```

Which would be accessible as `take_turn_path`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes

put if before `resources :board`: question of route priority

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `take_turn` in your case is a GET method on a collection.

```
resources :board do
  collection do
    get :take_turn
  end
  # OR
  get :take_turn, :on => :collection
end
```

p.s: out of the subject.. the best practice says that it is better to switch off wild-card routes to prevent unexpected behavior:

```
#match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```